# django urls doesn't work on a distant server

Tags: python, django, django-urls

my_project.urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from machina import urls as machina_urls
from allauth.account import views

def empty_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Empty View")

urlpatterns = [
    # path('', empty_view, name='empty_view'),
    path('admin', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^account/', include('allauth.urls')),
    # path('', include('allauth.urls')),
    # re_path('^', include('allauth.urls')),
```

I tested all the above possibilities.

On my computer, localhost:8000/account/login/ is just fine.

On a distant server (PlanetHoster), *my_domain/my_app/* says :

```
Using the URLconf defined in my_app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin
^account/
```

*/my_domain/my_app/account/* says :

```
Using the URLconf defined in my_app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
signup/ [name='account_signup'] 
login/ [name='account_login'] 
logout/ [name='account_logout'] 
The empty path didn't match any of these
```

/my_domain/my_app/account/login return to the homepage of my_domain.

And in settings.py

```
    LOGIN_URL = 'account/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/projects/project/'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/account/login"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optionnal"
```

I test with the empty_view in the urls, with Application URL : my_domain/my_app/account/login on the server, it works.

Comment: I'm worried by the leading slash in `/my_domain/` above. Paths don't change just because they're on a server. Did you mean to write something like `https://example.com/account`? Because you don't have a routing for `https://example.com/my_domain/my_app/account/`.
(Where I wrote `example` above imagine `mydomain`, stackoverflow doesn't allow other domains)

Comment: Thanks Halfer. You're right. It's https://example.com/my_app/account/login. I'm a newbie, here. Sorry for that. But I want to learn.